# how to add token auth to swagger + django rest framework?

Tags: django, documentation, django-rest-framework, swagger

I am using both great tools [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [Django-REST-Swagger](http://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger), however a few of my API views are under token authentication.

So now I'd like to add to my swagger doc page of my API the possibility to test those token auth api urls, including the Token header. How could I do this?.

A snapshot of my class API view is like this:

```
class BookList(APIView):
    """
    List all books, or create a new book.
    """
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    ...
```

Since Swagger auto detects a lot of stuff, I was expecting to notice about token auth, and ask me about token or user id in its web interface, but it doesn't. Hence I am testing it manually through CURL commands...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I answer myself since I made it work.

Actually Swagger settings has an option for this, api_key ->

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    "exclude_namespaces": [], # List URL namespaces to ignore
    "api_version": '0.1',  # Specify your API's version
    "api_path": "/",  # Specify the path to your API not a root level
    "enabled_methods": [  # Specify which methods to enable in Swagger UI
        'get',
        'post',
        'put',
        'patch',
        'delete'
    ],
    "api_key": '', # An API key
    "is_authenticated": False,  # Set to True to enforce user authentication,
    "is_superuser": False,  # Set to True to enforce admin only access
}
```

To me it wasn't that clear, but I've just input a valid token for testing user and it worked for the auth needed views :-)

Comment: I didn't succeed to make it work.
All my views has IsAuthenticated permission_class. I'm using Session, Basic, and Token authentication. How to add the api key and where is it ?

Comment: @aRkadeFR, with the 'api_key' field in SWAGGER_SETTINGS, mine is similar to this =>     "api_key": 'fasd12d1a7........c26f34r2f',

Answer (score 37):

If you're using token authentication, you might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547208/django-rest-framework-swagger-authentication-error)

Basically, you just need to add this to your `settings.py`:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'api_key': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'in': 'header',
            'name': 'Authorization'
        }
    },
}
```

In your Swagger UI page you should see an *Authorize* button. Click that and enter your *Authorization* value in the input text field.

Comment: Works like charm, i had to use "name:Auth-Token"

Comment: It didn't work for me. Tried both Auth-Token and Authorization.

Comment: it doesn't work for me either.  When I inspect element in browser, I see no request header newly added

Comment: Note that for this to work you have to supply "Token " followed by the actual token in the text field labelled "value" which shows up when the "Authorize" button is clicked, e.g. "Token 994...ee4b".

Answer (score 8):

My Problem was that after activating TokenAuthentification my api urls were not shown any more in the swagger UI due to an AuthentificationError. 
For me the solution was to activate both authentaction classes in the Django Rest Framework Settings:
SessionAuthentification -> for the Swagger UI
TokenAuthentification -> for the Rest Clients

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
)
```

}

Comment: can you please share what did you put for the SWAGGER_SETTINGS?

Comment: @matyas, would be great to have the settings

Comment: the Django cookiecutter repository comes with a pre-configured working DRF configuration. Run `pip install "cookiecutter>=1.7.0"` and `cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django` after filling out some values a Django project willl be generated that contains the correct DRF settings among a lot of other (useful) things.

Answer (score 8):

The schema view needs to have the permission of AllowAny. This allows the plugin to see which endpoints are available before the user has authenticated. The end points should still be protected if they are setup correctly. Example:

```
@api_view()
@renderer_classes([SwaggerUIRenderer, OpenAPIRenderer, renderers.CoreJSONRenderer])
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication))
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def schema_view(request):
    generator = schemas.SchemaGenerator(
        title='My API end points',
        patterns=my_urls,
        url="/api/v1/")
    return response.Response(generator.get_schema(request=request))
```

It is best to remove the SessionAuthentication and only use the TokenAuthentication but that is a matter of choice, here I have removed it

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
)
```

Be sure it add `'rest_framework.authtoken'` into your installed apps and remove the `CsrfViewMiddleware` from the middleware classes as it will no longer be needed. And the swagger settings

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'api_key': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'in': 'header',
            'name': 'Authorization'
        }
    },
    'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
    'JSON_EDITOR': True,
}
```

This will make swagger populate the token into all of the example curl commands as well, which is really nice to have. Leaving the session auth in place seems to disable this.

The swagger authorization dialog asks for the `api_key` which needs to be provided. Can not seem improve this, will update this post if I do.

Answer (score 2):

just add to you rest framework setting SessionAuthentication should be at the top

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'mymodule.authentication.CustomeAuthentication',
)
```

**Note: SessionAuthentication will use your Django login session**

**CustomeAuthentication  will be used for rest api for real use case.**

Answer (score 1):

if you are implementing the answer of @Melvic Ybanez with django-rest-swagger==2.2.0 and still doesn't work. Downgrade to django-rest-swagger==2.1.2.
Button authorize should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to change Swagger's default basic authentication to token authentication with this configuration but when try me button is pressed rest swagger accepts any authentication regardless of valid token.

Also note, when I added SessionAuthentication to my REST_FRAMEWORK in my settings.py, my api failed to be displayed on swagger docs.

django-rest-swagger==2.2.0
djangorestframework==3.7.7

settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Parser classes priority-wise for Swagger
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ) 
}

# SWAGGER SETTINGS
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'api_Key': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'in': 'header',
            'name': 'Token Authorization'
        }
    },
}
```

some helpful documentation https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-definitions-object

Answer (score 0):

Please use  `rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication` instead of `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication`.

My code is

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
         # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ),
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
        'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
        'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
        'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
        'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
        'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=86400),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=1),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
}

SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SHOW_REQUEST_HEADERS': True,
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'Bearer': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'Authorization',
            'in': 'header'
        }
    },
    'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
    'JSON_EDITOR': True,
    'SUPPORTED_SUBMIT_METHODS': [
        'get',
        'post',
        'put',
        'delete',
        'patch'
    ],
}
```

I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, beside customizing (inheriting) `OpenApiAuthenticationExtension`, I had to also import it some (doesn't matter which) `api.py`. Basically that's what I've done:

*settings.py*

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "mozilla_django_oidc",  # <-- My custom auth backend uses that.
    ...
    "rest_framework",
    ...
    "drf_spectacular",
    ...
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "apps.auth.backends.CustomBearerTokenAuthentication",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS": "drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema",
}
```

*apps.auth.backends:*

```py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend

class CustomBearerTokenAuthentication(BaseBackend):
    """Your custom Bearer Token Authentication Backend."""
    ...
```

*apps.auth.scheme:*

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from drf_spectacular.extensions import OpenApiAuthenticationExtension


class CustomTokenScheme(OpenApiAuthenticationExtension):
    target_class = "apps.auth.backends.CustomBearerTokenAuthentication"  # <-- Points to my custom auth backend.
    name = "CustomBearerTokenAuth"

    def get_security_definition(self, auto_schema):
        return {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "in": "header",
            "name": "Authorization",
            "description": _('Token-based authentication with required prefix "%s"')
            % "Bearer",
        }
```

*apps.users.api:*

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets
from apps.auth.scheme import CreooxTokenScheme  # <-- Only after this import it starts to work!
from .serializers import UserSerializer

User = get_user_model()


class UserViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
```

And finally you get:

[image: Available authorizations]