# Django REST Framework Swagger - Authentication Error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui

I followed the instructions [in the docs](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). So here's my view:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework import response, schemas
from rest_framework_swagger.renderers import OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer


@api_view()
@renderer_classes([OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer])
def schema_view(request):
    generator = schemas.SchemaGenerator(title='Bookings API')
    return response.Response(generator.get_schema(request=request))
```

And I added the following to my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^docs/', views.schema_view),
```

When I went to the `/docs/` page of my project, I got the following error:

```
401 : {"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."} http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/?format=openapi
```

In the browser console I got this message:

```
Unable to Load SwaggerUI init.js (line 57)
```

When I set the `permission_classes` of my `schema_view` to `AllowAny`, I was able to view my api docs. However, I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing this. Isn't there a way to login as an admin, or any other user to view the docs. Also, how do I provide the auth tokens when viewing this in the browser? Maybe I missed something in the docs.

Comment: What kind of authentication you are using in DRF?

Comment: I'm using token authentication.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think I've found the solution.

In the `settings.py`, I added the following settings:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'api_key': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'in': 'header',
            'name': 'Authorization'
        }
    },
}
```

Then when I load the page, I just click on the *Authorize* button at the upper right and enter this value in the *value* text field:

```
Token <valid-token-string>
```

However, I still needed to set the permission class of the `schema view` to `AllowAny`. The auth token just let me switch from different users, allowing me to view different set of endpoints.

Comment: Thank you very much man, this is the end of 2 hours investigation

Comment: In version 2.2.0 of django swagger, is there a bug with Authorize button. Downgrade to version 2.1.2 the problem is fixed.

Comment: @Melvic Is there any way to append the "Token " string to the token value? I am creating swagger specifications to be used to generate C# client using codegen, so am stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't there a way to login as an admin, or any other user to view the docs.

If your only use token authentication, first [create tokens for your users](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication), then access the resources by setting the header

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'
```

Comment: I do that when I call my serivces. However, isn't the swagger UI supposed to be accessed in the browser, not using cURL or Postman?

Comment: I'm not familiar with swagger, I don't know  if `swagger UI supposed to be accessed in the browser` without use SessionAuthentication. But you can also enable SessionAuthentication in DRF.

Comment: My API services use token authentication. The Swagger plugin is only there to generate the api docs. So it should be accessed in a browser AFAIK. I can't just change my API design to `SessionAuthentication` just so I can login to Swagger or something like that.

Comment: answer should be swagger specific only.